# Javascript not working on response.redirect using ajax ASP.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am redirecting the ASP.Net page to download page and i'm using ajax. The redirect page does work, the file is downloaded and the page that called the download is showing. I need to call javascript after the file is downloaded to remove the waiting screen.

I am first calling redirect then javascript to unblock the UI. to block the UI i'm doing that using onclientclick='block()';

```
  Response.Redirect("ExportFile.aspx, false);
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((this), this.GetType(), "alertAction", "alert('');unblock();", true);
```

even the alert isn't working so the JS isn't being fired at all.  I tired putting the code on the file download page but that doesn't work either. I even tried body onpageunload but that never fires either.

How can I redirect to a file download page then call JS to unblock the UI?

Comment: I don't know but If you will redirect the user, it's unusual block whole the page.

Comment: the problem is unblocking. I'm calling jquery block Ui. turns the page transparent black. now I need to unblock it but I can't get any JS to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Once response.redirect happens, no other code can execute.
I would suggest to write your redirect code in javascript and put it into your RegisterClientScriptBlock. Just make sure the unblock is before the window.location.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((this), this.GetType(), "alertAction", "unblock(); window.location.assign('yourPage.aspx');", true);
```

Comment: I did try that and that does work however the code to unblock fires first then the webpage starts the download.  The data is coming from a wcf service and that takes about 20 seconds. Because the unblock code fired the user will see nothing until the file is ready.

Comment: When the file is ready, can you fire off a javascript function?  Or use a custom event?  Then, you can just set the listener using the `RegisterClienScriptBlock` function, and once the file is ready, it'll unblock the page.

Comment: I did on page load of the export page after the WCF service got the data however that page disappears after the data is ready for save and no js is fired.

Answer (score 0):

boruchsiper is correct.  Also, once you've redirected them, you're on a different page (if my assumption is correct that you're redirecting to a different page).  You would want to fire off this line after arriving at the new page, so you'd want it in that page's code behind in the `Load()` function:

`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock((this), this.GetType(), "alertAction", "alert('');unblock();", true);`

You may want to include a query string in that redirect URL to tell that page to take that action.

Comment: I've tried that also, I also changed the script manager to be a startup script. even Body=onunload won't fire on the export page.
since page A redirects to a download file page that page is never even seen. for some reason to download a file or export data you have to redirect the page